# Express.js req.session variable not storing session variables through different routes

Tags: session, node.js, express

Cannot acces s`req.session variable`. I set `req.session.username` to `someVariable` but I get
undefined. Does the following Express setup let me access the req.session variable in every route?

```
app = express.createServer(
    express.logger(),
    express.cookieParser(),
    express.session({ secret: 'keyboard cat' })
    )
```

Express website seems uses in this way.

EDIT:

Here is some other code I use:

```
if(result[0] != undefined && result[0].Password == req.body.user.pass){
    console.log("login successfull");

    //Setting in the cookies some variable useful later
    req.session.userAuthenticated = true;
    req.session.username = result[0].Username;
    req.session.projects = result[0].Projects;
```

This is part of the `/login` route. In this part I check if a user correctly input the password and if he is registered. If I do a `console.log(req.session.username)` I get the correct username of the user logged in.

In another route, call it `/wathever` I do a check after a db retrieval like this

```
if(projects[i].name == projectName && projects[i].username == req.session.username){
```

`projectName` is something I receive as `POST` from the user, and it works, it has the correct content, but if I check `req.session.username` I receive `undefined`. It seems the session variable is not containing what I put inside in the previous route...

Thanks

Comment: You probably doing something wrong, but not there, in your routes. Can you paste more code?

Comment: Done, sorry for not having put that from the beginning.

Comment: I have the same issue, Can you tell me what was the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `result[0].Username` && `result[0].Projects` are not undefined.

Also you have another problem in your code, you don't check if `req.body.user` and `req.body.user.pass` are undefined. For example I could make a post request to your site with the params "test=ok", so without those vars and it would show me an Internal Error page.

Comment: For the first point I'm sure they are not :). I check them... while for the second point, you are right, but still it doesn't really solve the problem... Thanks anyway :)

Comment: I can only guess what's the problem, I need the whole code to see exactly what you did wrong (because I don't see the real problem in these small snippets of code shown).